# What does "self-conscious" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

At 00:37 of this video "Valspar Color For The Colorblind" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ea_xOqNvntA) the woman say "I've had moments where girls would make fun of me for not knowing girly shades, and I felt self-conscious about it."
What does "self-conscious" mean in this sentence?
Does she mean she felt "embarrassed" or she herself noticed that (she didn't know what are girly shades) as well?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hmm, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-conscious. Why doesn't the definition work?

Answer (score 2):

*Self-conscious*, while it literally means *aware of oneself*, often really means *shy* or *afraid someone will say something about oneself.*